# 2^63 - 1 == 2^63, precision errors in MATLAB 2012a

Tags: matlab

I'm dealing with arbitrarily large numbers in MATLAB, I've been futzing with a script for a while and finally found out that my problem wasn't a logic error.

It was this:

```
>> 2^63 - 1 == 2^63

ans = 

     1
```

In MATLAB 2012a, without additional libraries, is there a way to handle large numbers of up to `2^100`?

**Edit**:
Apparently, the precision error happens as soon as `2^54`.

**Second Edit**:
According to [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947819/263-1-263-precision-errors-in-matlab-2012a#comment44290841_27947819), I can use `vpa`. This actually solves the problem quite nicely:

```
>> vpa(sym(2^63)) - vpa(sym(2^63) - 1)

ans =

1.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You're near. If you're representing an integer number with a floating point variable then maximum integer number you can represent without errors is 2^53. See [flintmax](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html).

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "additional libraries".  The Symbolic Math Toolbox provides `vpa` (variable precision arithmetic) for this

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I used the following line of code to see when the problem starts: `[(1:63)', [2.^(1:63)'] == [2.^(1:63)' - 1]]`.

Comment: @Peter I don't have the luxury of including additional Toolboxes. VPA is installed and it works great. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `vpa` is provided as part of the symbolic math toolbox.  It performs "infinite precision" math using a number representation other than CPU-native floating point values.  This does mean, however, that arithmetic will be MUCH slower, and that numbers will take up much more space.

Comment: `vpa` has no infinite precision, but you can specify the precision you need. Check `digits`. If `vpa` is available this is definitely the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab comes with an JRE. Use the java class `java.math.BigDecimal` to work around.